# In Highchart, use JSON file instead of csvURL

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I've just started using `HighCharts` & I've requirement in which I want to publish a chart very similar to one explained [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-ajax/).

But in above example as you can see it is fetching data from `csvURL`.
Instead of CSV, I want to use JSON data, since I'm fetching it from a RestAPI.
JSON example is [here](https://jsonblob.com/f991c920-5ce4-11e8-9663-3b222cf49057).

Please note that JSON format is not strict can can be changed of required.

Please suggest.
*Thank You*

Answer (score 2):

Highcharts supports JSON as well as CSV (although the most examples seem to use CSV).

The [Highcharts documentation](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data) lists two functions `data.columnsURL` and `data.rowsURL` that are JSON equivalents to `data.csvURL`.

As JSON file provides a list of rows, you can use `data.rowsURL` in the same way as your jsfiddle example uses `data.csvURL`.

Highcharts provides a small example to [data.rowsURL](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/data/livedata-rows). Of course, the `series` object has to be implemented to create the desired multiline chart.

Comment: Hi, do you know data format rowsURL for several series? It works for me as [[1,2,3][4,5,6]] (draw two series), but not work with this format:[ [ [ time, 1], [ time2, 2] ], [ [time1, 6], [time2, 4] ] ] :(